# Python 3 for loop error inside of a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to put a for loop inside of a dict. (See my code bellow)

```
tempdict["data"] = {
    "id": words[0],
    for j in range(1, 100):
        tempdict[fieldnames[j]] = words[j]
}
```

So, I'm reading out of a CSV file and converting it to JSON. (This is to automate a process at work)

Not sure if there is anything else to add, just ask if you need to know more.

I would appreciate any help I can get :)

so, extra context: 
I'm trying to map the value from the CSV file to the dict with the key as one of the fieldnames (See fieldnames bellow)

```
fieldnames = ["id", "subscriber-A-01", "subscriber-A-02", "subscriber-A-03", "subscriber-A-04", "subscriber-A-05", "subscriber-A-06", "subscriber-A-07", "subscriber-A-08", "subscriber-A-09", "subscriber-A-10", "subscriber-B-01", "subscriber-B-02", "subscriber-B-03", "subscriber-B-04", "subscriber-B-05", "subscriber-B-06", "subscriber-B-07", "subscriber-B-08", "subscriber-B-09", "subscriber-B-10", "subscriber-C-01", "subscriber-C-02", "subscriber-C-03", "subscriber-C-04", "subscriber-C-05", "subscriber-C-06", "subscriber-C-07", "subscriber-C-08", "subscriber-C-09", "subscriber-C-10", "subscriber-D-01", "subscriber-D-02", "subscriber-D-03", "subscriber-D-04", "subscriber-D-05", "subscriber-D-06", "subscriber-D-07", "subscriber-D-08", "subscriber-D-09", "subscriber-D-10", "subscriber-E-01", "subscriber-E-02", "subscriber-E-03", "subscriber-E-04", "subscriber-E-05", "subscriber-E-06", "subscriber-E-07", "subscriber-E-08", "subscriber-E-09", "subscriber-E-10", "subscriber-F-01", "subscriber-F-02", "subscriber-F-03", "subscriber-F-04", "subscriber-F-05", "subscriber-F-06", "subscriber-F-07", "subscriber-F-08", "subscriber-F-09", "subscriber-F-10", "subscriber-G-01", "subscriber-G-02", "subscriber-G-03", "subscriber-G-04", "subscriber-G-05", "subscriber-G-06", "subscriber-G-07", "subscriber-G-08", "subscriber-G-09", "subscriber-G-10", "subscriber-H-01", "subscriber-H-02", "subscriber-H-03", "subscriber-H-04", "subscriber-H-05", "subscriber-H-06", "subscriber-H-07", "subscriber-H-08", "subscriber-H-09", "subscriber-H-10", "subscriber-I-01", "subscriber-I-02", "subscriber-I-03", "subscriber-I-04", "subscriber-I-05", "subscriber-I-06", "subscriber-I-07", "subscriber-I-08", "subscriber-I-09", "subscriber-I-10", "subscriber-J-01", "subscriber-J-02", "subscriber-J-03", "subscriber-J-04", "subscriber-J-05", "subscriber-J-06", "subscriber-J-07", "subscriber-J-08", "subscriber-J-09", "subscriber-J-10", "DISPLAY_TYPE", "stationCode"]
```

So, from subscriber-A-1 to subscriber-J-10 should be mapped to value 1 to 100 of the CSV file.

**Update**

This is how I made it work.

```
tempdict["data"] = dict(zip(fieldnames[1:100], words[1:100]))
tempdict["data"].update({"DISPLAY_TYPE": words[102]})
```

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Just to be clear the syntax you're using of "a for loop inside a dict" is actually called a "dict comprehension" (as analogous to the older "list comprehension" syntax in Python. Knowing that might help you find answers in the future.

Comment: As it is your syntax is not even correct. Please explain what you were hoping to achieve and what result you obtained instead (in this case it should be a SyntaxError but you didn't specify that). Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pair the sliced list of keys and the sliced list of values with `zip` and pass the zipped pairs to the `dict` constructor to build the desired dict instead:

```
tempdict['data'] = dict(zip(fieldnames[:101], words[:101]))
```

Comment: I see. I don't think you need to treat the `id` key any differently from the rest of the keys then. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I see, I want to map to ID manually though. How would I go from position 1 to 100?

Comment: Also, the data key ends up being empty with this.

Comment: Don't worry, I got it to work I was just being dumb and had some stuff the wrong way around.